# Listener doesn't receive msgs if launchs Talker with system command

Tags: linux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the example in the tutorial of subscriber and listener everything works well, subscriber sends and listener receives messages.
Using Linux, why if I launch the subscriber program from the listener with the command system in a new terminal, the listener doesn't receive any messages?

```
    #include "ros/ros.h"
    #include <std_msgs/Int32.h>   
    #include <signal.h> 
    #include <sstream>
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {    
      ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");
      ros::NodeHandle n;
      ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Int32>("chat", 1);
      ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
      int count = 0;
      while (ros::ok())
      {
        std_msgs::Int32 msg;
        msg.data = getpid();
        ROS_INFO("%i", msg.data);
        chatter_pub.publish(msg);
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
        ++count;   
   }    
    return 0;
}
```

LISTENER:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>

void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::Int32::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard: [%i]", msg->data);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 int  status = system("gnome-terminal -x ./talker");
 printf("STATUS: %d", status);

  ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chat", 1000, chatterCallback);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
  int count = 0;
  while (ros::ok())
  {
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();


     ++count;
      }
  return 0;
}
```

STATUS:2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187517/listener-doesn%27t-receive-msgs-if-launchs-talker-with-system-command/) by [genzostyle](https://answers.ros.org/users/13206/genzostyle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-07-23**:
what happens if you do  int  status = system("gnome-terminal -x rosrun your_package talker");

**Comment by [genzostyle](https://answers.ros.org/users/13206/genzostyle/) on 2014-07-23**:
With
int status = system("gnome-terminal -x rosrun talker");
listener opens a new terminal, but appear the text "There was an error creating the child process for this terminal. Failed to execute child process "rosrun" (No such file or directory)"
and two buttons on the right: "Profile Preferences" and Relaunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to make sure that the executable for *talker* is on the same folder where you execute your *listener* or provide the absolute path to the *talker* command when you call *system()*.

Also note that **your process will be frozen until the *system()* call returns** (when the process *talker* finishes).

You might encounter problems because of environment variables needed by ROS not being set when you call *system()*.

One more thing, ***system()* is evil** and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/) is why. If you are trying to start automatically your *talker* when your *listener* starts, **you should use a [roslaunch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch) file**.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1